# I want to write the 'Class_Scores' to a csv file in rows(Name on one side score on the other), how do I do that?

Tags: python, list, file, csv

```
Class_Scores = [['James', 1]['Frank', 2]['Mark', 3]]

with open('Class One Scores.csv','w') as file:
    for index in range(0, len(Class_Scores)):
        file.write(str(Class_Scores))
```

When I type this into python it works and opens the file but it does not do it in rows.

Comment: Don't use `file` as variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class_Scores = [['James', 1],['Frank', 2],['Mark', 3]]

with open('Class One Scores.csv','w') as file:
    # unpack name and score from each sublist
    for name, score in Class_Scores:
          # write each name and score plus a newline 
          file.write("{},{}\n".format(name,score))
```

Your code is writing the str representation of your Class_scores list not the contents.

```
In [3]: str(Class_Scores)
Out[3]: "[['James', 1], ['Frank', 2], ['Mark', 3]]"
```

You would need [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to do it passing the whole list:

```
import  csv
Class_Scores = [['James', 1],['Frank', 2],['Mark', 3]]
with open('Class One Scores.csv','w') as file:
    wr = csv.writer(file,delimiter=",")
    wr.writerows(Class_Scores)
```